# Simplified proof that brownian motion in dimension 2 does not hit points/singletons

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Suppose $B(t)$ is a standard Brownian motion in $\mathbb{R}^2$ started from the origin. It is will known that almost surely, for any point $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ (including (0,0)), $P(B(t) = (x,y) \mbox{for some t >0})=0$, i.e. 2-d Brownian motion does not hit any particular point with probability 1.

A proof of this fact is given in Corollary 2.23 in the excellent book Morters and Peres, [here](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/%7Ealdous/205B/bmbook.pdf). This proof however seems somewhat over complicated! It relies on the fact that the image of Brownian motion in the plane has Lebesgue measure 0. Another intuitive reason as to why this must be true is that the two component brownian motions cannot both equal zero at the same time, since at any particular point they are independent, continuous random variables. I cannot though come up with a simple argument for why this must be true based on this fact.

My question then is: does anyone know of a simpler proof of this fact that is of the flavor "The two component brownian motions cannot be equal to zero at the same time, since at any particular point they are independent, continuous random variables?"

Comment: "Another intuitive reason as to why this must be true is that the two component brownian motions cannot both equal zero at the same time, since at any particular point they are independent, continuous random variables." A problem here is that to conclude you would need to take the union of uncountably many measure zero events, one for each time.

Comment: Thanks @LorenzoNajt! This is sort of the hurdle that I'm hitting trying to write my own simple proof, but I thought there might be a clever way around this without resorting to the "big guns" of the result of Levy on the measure of the image.

Comment: @LorenzoNajt, even in the setting where, rather than considering Brownian motion components, the components are independent Gaussian processes that are smooth with a finite (countable) number of zeros, and non-degenerate covariances, I still cannot get a proof of this flavour through... It seems as if this "intuitive" idea as to why a non-degenerate bivariate Gaussian process cannot have zeros does not readily translate to a proof even in simpler cases.

Comment: In my stochastic calculus course we proved it computing the probability that the BM hits (after exiting from it) a ball centered in the origin and of radius $r$, and then taking the limit for $r → 0$.

Answer (score 1):

If we take a 2-d fractional Brownian motion, then the real and imaginary parts are both continuous Gaussian processes, and they're independent, and yet the result you're looking for is false: the process is recurrent, i.e. hits points. I don't know who proved this first, but it is mentioned in the paper "Notes on the Two-Dimensional Fractional Brownian Motion" by Baudoin and Nualart. So I don't think you can get the result you want in the manner you are hoping. On the other hand, the zero set of 1-d BM has Hausdorff dimension 1/2, so you are asking whether two random and independent sets of dimension 1/2 intersect. It could be that there is some way to see that they don't intersect with probability 1 using that fact. I don't know if this works, but it occurs to me because I was once told (by Jay Rosen) that, heuristically, 4-d BM doesn't have double points because the Brownian path has Hausdorff dimension 2, even in higher dimensions than 2, and therefore there is space for 2 of them in R^4, but not in lower dimensional spaces (where you do have double points).

A fun way to prove what you are after is as follows. The complex exponential function is analytic, and therefore by Levy's Theorem on conformal invariance exp(B_t) is a time-changed Brownian motion, where B_t = R_t + i I_t and R, I are independent 1-d BM's. But it can never hit 0, because e^z is never 0. QED